# Adding a new row containing dropdown box C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three dropdownlists on a single row, and a button 
    
at the end. What I am trying to achieve is OnClick of the "add" button, a new row should be created under the previous row, along with another "add" button.

I will want this process to repeat up to 30 time i.e. there will be 29 "add" buttons.

Your responses will be very much appreciated.

```
 default.aspx
<asp:Table ID="TblUni" runat="server" Width="600" Height="60">
                            <asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableCell><asp:Label ID="LblUni" runat="server" Text="University"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><asp:Label ID="LblSchool" runat="server" Text="School"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:TableCell><asp:Label ID="LblDepartment" runat="server" Text="Type"></asp:Label></asp:TableCell>
                            </asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableRow>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpUniversity" runat="server" Width="200" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpUni_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>                    
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpSchool" runat="server" Width="200" AutoPostBack ="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drpSchool_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpDept" runat="server" Width="200" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </asp:TableCell>
                            <asp:TableCell>
                                <asp:Button ID="addUSD" Text="+" runat="server" OnClick="addUSD_Click" />                                    
                            </asp:TableCell>                             </asp:TableRow>                                                                 
                        </asp:Table>
      default.aspx.cs
      protected void addUSD(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {//empty event
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, what is your question?

Comment: Please show us some code and attempts you've made

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build a datagridview with three column of type drop down combo box, and it will automatically add the rows